# How to enable warning C6067 during (WDM) Windows driver compilation in VS 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, wdm, windows-driver

I'm using a WDM driver project in VS 2022. In case of the following code snippet:

```
extern "C" NTSTATUS NTAPI DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,
                                      PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    DbgPrint("v=%s", 123);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `DbgPrint` has an incorrect `%s` specifier, which will cause that driver to crash.

The VS editor can see it and shows me an underlined [warning C6067](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6067?view=msvc-170):

[image]

But when I compile it, that warning is not shown and the project compiles successfully, even though the settings for my project are set to "Level4 (/W4)".

Any idea how to enable that warning C6067 during compilation?

Comment: Impossible. C6067 is a Code Analysis warning and is not associated with the compiler warnings.

Comment: @273K: OK. Is there any other way to catch that incorrect %s printf-type specifier with a warning? I know that VS compiler can do it for a regular user-mode C++ project.

Comment: @273K, aren't analyzer warning shown up with `/analyze` compiler option?

Comment: IDK. I can't find `DbgVPrint()`, otherwise you could write own `DbgPrint()` with the parameter `_Printf_format_string_ char const* const format`

Comment: @AlexGuteniev IDK, I am not aware of such option.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev: great find, thanks. It does enable that C6067 during compilation, along with a bunch of others. But I guess I can disable the ones that I don't need.

Comment: Try use of `/analyze:external-`

Comment: @273K no, it doesn't do it. But there's an easy fix. I can suppress those warnings with: `#pragma warning(disable: 28023)` for instance.

Comment: Alternatively, you can have [rules set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/analyze-code-analysis?view=msvc-170#ruleset-options) to enable only your warnings rather than having that in code

Comment: @AlexGuteniev thanks. I'm not very familiar with that. Do you want to post more details on both solutions in a separate post? I'll mark it as the answer then.

Comment: I added an answer that solves your task using `.ruleset`. But generally I suggest reading the documentation about [`/analyze`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/analyze-code-analysis). It is a powerful tool with a plenty of options, it has a whole subtree in Configuration Properties of MSVC projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual MSVC compiler warnings are `C4xxx` and `C5xxx`. Warnings with other number format are Code Analysis warnings.

The [`/analyze`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/analyze-code-analysis) option enables code analysis, which makes the compiler deliberately analyze code semantic for red flags. It has lot more warnings. Some are implemented by the compiler itself, some are available via plugins (like C++ Code Guidelines).

There's an option `/analyze:only` to run with code analysis, but without compilation. This makes sense for larger programs, as code analysis is way slower than the usual compilation, so you compile without `/analyze` at all, and have a scheduled run of `/analyze:only` on a build server.

To control large number of various Code Analysis warnings in a more convenient way than pragma or compiler switches, there are `.ruleset` files. They are in `%VSINSTALLDIR%\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets`. They can be edited via IDE, or as XML files, so that you can create your own `.ruleset` file, based on an existing one, and suppress any warnings.

For example if you run the compiler with `/analyze:only` on the following program, which does not only try to format an integer as a string, but also tries to obtain that integer by indirection of a null pointer:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *i = nullptr;
    printf("%s", *i);
}
```

You'll have the following output:

```
D:\temp2\test.cpp(6) : warning C6067: _Param_(2) in call to 'printf' must be the address of a string. Actual type: 'int'.
D:\temp2\test.cpp(6) : warning C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'i'. : Lines: 5, 6
```

If you create the following `only_format_string.ruleset` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="Format Strings" Description="I'm only interested in format strings" ToolsVersion="17.0">
  <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.Analyzers.NativeCodeAnalysis" RuleNamespace="Microsoft.Rules.Native">
    <Rule Id="C6067" Action="Warning" />
  </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

And run the conpiler with `/analyze:only /analyze:ruleset only_format_string.ruleset`, you'll have only C6067, but not C6011.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is indeed a very powerful technique. I would have only one complaint about placing those rules into the `%VSINSTALLDIR%\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets` directory - it doesn't travel along with your solution, in case you have to move it to another computer.

Answer (score 1):

C6067 and other warnings with numbers 6000+ are Code Analysis warnings and are not associated with the compiler warnings.

As suggested in the comments, [`/analyze /analyze:external-`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/analyze-code-analysis?view=msvc-170) enables Code Analysis warnings in your files only while compiling.